# SwiftUI @ViewBuilder issue in Xcode 12 fails to compile project in View extension

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode12, viewbuilder, xcode12beta6

Hi I am facing an issue in project/build compilation in Xcode 12 Beta 1-6 (SwiftUI 2.0), In scenario, Having Custom `modifier` in `View` extension.

```
extension View {
    public func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder _ alert: () -> TextFieldAlert) -> some View {
        self.modifier(TextFieldAlertModifier(isPresented: isPresented, alert: alert()))
    }
}
```

As you can observe in code snippets, Once I remove `@ViewBuilder` from param list, then I am able to compile & run build.
If this attribute exist in params then I am facing following compilation error `(Type of expression is ambiguous without more context)`

[image]

I don't see any problem with SwiftUI 1.0 (Xcode 11), Does anyone of you see this issue ? & what might be reason of it. Any hint would be ver appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's inside that builder block? Does it really returns `TextFieldAlert`?

Comment: Xcode 12 has an initializer like this `public func alert(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> Alert) -> some View`, probably signature is ambigious for compiler somehow (may be Alert is also a `ViewBuilder`)